# Char comparison on if statement doesn't evaluate to true

Tags: c, if-statement, char, comparison

Why doesn't the following IF statement evaluate to true, even though sex[i] has the value of M char?

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
if (sex[i] == 'M' || sex[i] == 'm')
```

What i'm trying to do, is create an array of characters that holds several values for strings or characters. In this case, it's a character and it works outside the if function, if i print sex[0] i get M.

Oh, and i know that the variable needs to be declared like this

```
char sex[size][sizeofstring]
```

The entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[10][256], sex[10][256];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf ("Insert the name of the person %d and her gender, M for male F for female\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
        scanf(" %c", sex[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        if (*sex[i] == 'M' || *sex[i] == 'm')
            printf ("\n%s", name[i]);
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        if (sex[i] == 'F' || sex[i] == 'f')
            printf ("\n%s", name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wait, why are you allocating a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Because i googled on how to create an array for char, and that's what they told me to do. I assume the second dimension will hold the amount of characters the string has, and the first is how many strings you want the array to have.

Comment: So, try `if (*sex[i] == 'M' || *sex[i] == 'm')`

Comment: Because `sex[i]` is a characters string, while 'M' or 'm' is just a character (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the declaration

```
char sex[size][sizeofstring];
```

use of

```
if (sex[i] == 'M' || sex[i] == 'm')
```

does not work since it becomes a pointer comparison operation. It is equivalent to:

```
char* p = sex[i];
void* p1 = 78;   // Assuming ASCII encoding.
                 // 'M' is an int. The int is converted to a pointer.
void* p2 = 102;  // Again, assuming ASCII encoding
if ( p == p1 || p == p2 )
```

That explains why the conditional in the `if` statement never evaluates to true.

**Solution**

You should use:

```
if ( strcmp(sex[i], "M") == 0 || strcmp(sex[i], "m") == 0)
```

If your compiler supports the non-standard case insensitive string comparison function, `stricmp`, you can combine the two tests.

```
if ( stricmp(sex[i], "M") == 0 )
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, when i use the strcmp function you just gave me, it only prints out 2/3 values for M. The if (*sex[i] == 'M' || *sex[i] == 'm') works out 3/3 though.

Comment: @AlexRD, `*sex[i] == 'M'` is a less stricter test. It will evaluate to `true` regardless of what's in `sex[i][1]` as long as the value in `sex[i][0]` is `'M'`.

Comment: You can combine the two tests by using `stricmp()`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this, i need to read up more on pointers. However, with this IF statement, it never prints out the third value in a 3 run loop.

Comment: @AlexRD Use `%s` instead of `%c`

Comment: Was it because i was comparing a string to a character?

Comment: @AlexRD, When you use `%c`, only one character is read. When you use `%s`, a string is read. If that string happens to contain one character, the string is still null terminated. Hence, `strcmp` works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the long version:

```
char arr[size_1][size_2]
```

means that I want to store stringS(plural).

```
arr[i]
```

means that I want to access the i'th string

```
arr[i][j]
```

means that I want to access the j'th character of i'th string.

Try this:

```
char sex[2][30] = {
{"My name is this"},
{"Your name is this"}};

printf("I'm a single character: %c\n", sex[0][5]);
printf("I'm a string, group of characters: %s\n", sex[0]);
```